# Wordpress - After Login Redirecting to custom page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication

I'm trying to send the user to my custom page below, however the `$username` is leaving blank in the URL when the user logins

```
/connections/username/profile/edit/group/1/
```

The below code is working perfectly fine, except that $username is not executing properly

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();
     $username =  $current_user->user_login;
    $url = home_url( "/connections/$username/profile/edit/group/1/" ); 

    //is there a user to check?
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;
        } else {
            return esc_url( $url );
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

after wordpress 4.5 get_currentuserinfo() deprecated so you can use code

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    global $current_user;
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     $username =  $current_user->user_login;
    $url = home_url( "/connections/$username/profile/edit/group/1/" ); 

    //is there a user to check?
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;
        } else {
            return esc_url( $url );
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: $username is where the problem lies.. It is not passing it in the address bar but working on template page

Comment: did you try  $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); this?

Comment: It is only executing in the template page but not in the address bar.